# Why is my output printing in wrong order in selection sort?

Tags: selection-sort

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[6] = {6,1,3,4,5,2};
    int size = 6;

    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        int smallest = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {

            if(a[j] < a[smallest])
            {
                   smallest = j;

            }

            if(smallest != i)
            {
                int z = a[smallest];
                a[smallest] = a[j];
                a[j] = z;
            }

            else
            {
                a[i] = a[smallest];
            }

        }
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
         printf("%d, ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

So I have 3 problems.

1. Output printing in descending order. I want to print it as 1,2,3,4,5,6 but the actual output is 6,5,4,3,2,1. Why?

2)When I changed the printf statement as `printf("%d, ", a[size - i]);`  it gave output as 32767, 1,2,3,4. Why?

3. When I changed the "for" condition in the last "for statement" above "printf" satement as `for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)`  it gave output as 0,1,2,3,4,5, . Why?

Comment: For Q2: accessing `a[size - i]` yields undefined behavior when `i == 0` (in your case, you see a "junk" data, i.e., of a non-properly allocated memory address).

Comment: For Q1: I'd start with simply changing the `<` to `>` (the fact that you haven't, implies that this code is just a copy-paste from somewhere perhaps?).

Comment: @goodvibration Where are we talking about. I did a similar thing in If statement, but i did not get the output in that case.

Comment: @goodvibration now it prints in ascending order. I guess my indexing was wrong. I wrote ```printf("%d, ", a[size - i - 1]); & it works.